# Raising Timer Interrupt in C

Tags: c, timer, interrupt

I want to start multiple timers through the code which can be identified uniquely, with specific duration (say 5 seconds), also, I want the code to keep running as it is until an interrupt is raised, so using a while(1) loop/sleep(secs)  will not help. And when this interrupt is called a certain code is to be run, followed by a return to where the instruction pointer was when the interrupt was raised. How do I implement this in Linux(Ubuntu) while using gcc?

```
void interrupt_handler(){
     //code

}
int main(){
    // Some Operations
    int t1 = Start_Timer(INTEGER, );
    op1;
    op2;
    op3;
    op4; //Suppose Interrupt is raised here(if timer not stopped), then interrupt corresponding to timer above is raised handled by interrupt_handler()
    int t2 = Start_Timer(INTEGER_O, );
    op5;
    op6;
    op7;
    op8;
    timer_stop(t2);
    //left operations
}
```

EDIT: The interrupt are meant to be signals.

Comment: What kind of interrupts? Hardware interrupts or signals?

Comment: @MrBens, signals, sorry, will add that

Comment: Start by looking in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling.

Comment: After that, what you'll probably want to do is to create a signal handler, and use sigaction.